# Remove scrollbars (x and y) from iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I have a jsFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/ELf3b/)**...

I'm trying to display the site inside the iframe, but without the scrollbars. I've tried `overflow: hidden;` on the iframe, both in the head style and in-line. It's not working.

```
.iphone5 {
    background-image: url("images/iphone5-upright.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 631px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto 30px;
    position: relative;
}
iframe { overflow: hidden; }
```

I'm also trying to maintain the ability to scroll...

Where am I going wrong?

Edit:  If not removing the sidebar, why not hide it? Is there a way to do that with margins and padding?

Comment: you'd have to be able to style the target url's page to stop the scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some trick like this. So that you can hide the scrollbar from users.

Wrap your `iframe` with a `span` element and apply below **CSS**.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="iphone5">
    <span class="frameBox">
    <iframe  style="float: left; width: 277px; height: 445px; margin: 93px 0 0 26px; src="" id="iframe"></iframe>
</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.frameBox {
   width:275px;
   height:520px;
   overflow:hidden;
   display:block;
}
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ELf3b/7/)**

Comment: Like I said below... I need to maintain the ability to scroll. I basically want this to work like a smart phone... and just scroll with the mousewheel or arrow keys.

Comment: You, sir, have lead me in the direction I needed. Very good. Been working on this for a couple days... keep on coding my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `scrolling="no"` as an attribute to the `iframe` tag.

Seems to work in Chrome. Example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ELf3b/2/

Just style your iframe dimensions and scrollbars accordingly. You might also try a css rule like:

```
iframe[scrolling='no'] { overflow: hidden; }
```

To maintain the vertical scrolling, try nesting the iframe in another element as suggested by Prasanth K C.

Comment: That removes the overflow scrollbars, but takes away the ability to scroll. I need to be able to maintain scrolling ability. I've edited my original question to reflect that.